widget.interact defining a parameter inside a function doesn't update the slider
I am trying to initialize the value of a function's parameter otherwise controlled via a widget.
I want to do that on the first call of that function, and subsequently respond to the user inputs.
For instance:
import ipywidgets as widgets
init = True
def test(a):
    global init
    if init:
        a = 0.5       # would in practice need some processing
        init = False
    print(a)
    
widgets.interact(test, a = (0,2,.1))

I know of the way to set the initial widget value by having the function's parameter set in the definition:
import ipywidgets as widgets
init = True
def test(a=0.5):
    print(a)
    
widgets.interact(test, a = (0,2,.1))

but this is not what I am trying to achieve.
The naive first example above doesn't do what I want, but I am wondering whether what I am trying to achieve is even possible conceptually. After all, the widget is not an "indicator" but a "control"...
In other words, is there a way to "talk back" to the widget and update its value from within the function it controls?

Are you set on using interact()? I think you could use a slider with a value setting and then use on_value_change(change) to control it via your function. I think. I'm not quite following what you mean to happen after the initial setting?

What I meant to say about the first example is that, while it does set the value of "a" to 0.5 (as confirmed by the print statement), the slider remains locked to the median value between 0 and 2, i.e. 1. I am looking for a way to update the slider so that it reflects that init value of 0.5 (again, this initial value would be computed, so it cannot be set a priori as done in example 2). And no, I am not set on using interact().

I think I got what you are after now. I put two approaches with the one closer to what is illustrated in the documentation maybe being the slightly simpler option. Yet, maybe it doesn't work for your use and so there is an approach that is more in line with setting the slider value initially inside the function.

Sticking with interact(), you can pass in a widget to specify options, such as the starting value for the slider, as discussed here and in the ipywidgets documentation for interact() where you it states interact(f, x=widgets.IntSlider(min=-10, max=30, step=1, value=10));. Just adding that approach into your code snippet:
import ipywidgets as widgets
init = 0.5
def test(a):
    print(a)
    
widgets.interact(test, a = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=2, step=0.1, value=init));

That will start with 0.5 and not in the middle of the range of the slider.
That above hews closer to the documentation; however, you could actually set the initial value from within the function, too.
For this example, I keep closer to your code and don't set an initial value in the slider, yet do the setting within the function as you ask. The key is accessing & setting the value attribute of the slider after assigning the slider a handle, like so:
import ipywidgets as widgets
init = True
slider = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=2, step=0.1)
def test(a):
    global init
    if init:
        slider.value = 0.5
        init = False
    print(a)
    
widgets.interact(test, a = slider)

Illustrating the situation where you don't know the initial value and you do something with value as well
Putting your code together with simulating the situation where the value at the outset is determined by something else (a priori not knowing the value) here where I pick a random number at the start, gives the following:
from ipywidgets import interact
import ipywidgets as widgets
import random
max_secret = 10
secret = random.randint(1, max_secret)

slider = widgets.IntSlider(
    value=secret,
    min=0,
    max= max_secret,
    step=1,
    description='Choose value:',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'},
    readout=True,
    readout_format='d'
)

def test_func(x):
    output.update(f"The current value is: {slider.value}          That value times 5 is {slider.value * 5}")

output = display(f"The starting value is: {slider.value}", display_id=True)

interact(test_func, x=slider);

And a variation of that hewing closer to the version where the slider value is set in the function as the title addressed:
from ipywidgets import interact
import ipywidgets as widgets
import random
max_secret = 10
secret = random.randint(1, max_secret)
init = True
slider = widgets.IntSlider(
    min=0,
    max= max_secret,
    step=1,
    description='Choose value:',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
    style= {'description_width': 'initial'},
    readout=True,
    readout_format='d'
)

def test_func(x):
    global init
    if init:
        slider.value = secret
        init = False
    output.update(f"The current value is: {slider.value}          That value times 5 is {slider.value * 5}")

output = display(f"The starting value is: {secret}", display_id=True)

interact(test_func, x=slider);


That's great. Thanks for the time writing this. I definitely learned a lot.
